# How to check GPS signal whether is available on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gps

as topic...

I try to use the didError method , but it does not works ...
if I am in room , the iPhone sdk seem insist try to got the location as it could in my app, even the value is not accurate ...

how to deal with such problem ?

thanks for your help in advance .

Regards

Comment: Wow, can someone with the appropriate rights PLEASE clean up this question and title?  I'm about to gouge my eyes out with a friggen teaspoon!

Comment: what's wrong ? I am not native english speaker , sorry for my fault if I made wrong spell, but does it is most important than the question ???

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when I get a location from the core location service, if the verticalAccuracy was less than 0, that means the GPS isn't being used to get the position.  It seems that you can't get an altitude from the Wifi/Cell methods of determining a location.